# Kotlin, lists zip, must search list for x, y pair

Tags: kotlin

I am new to Kotlin so please forgive me if this has been already solved.

I am trying to compare x, y of input to two lists, used zip to combine the lists to coordinates. I need to reject duplicate entries to the lists and return a message.

Do I need to zip the two lists again in the other function? And how do I use two values as a pair to search the list?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I haven't tried anything yet, I'm not sure where to start.

I'm working on JetBrains Kotlin Core course and their Cinema Manager project.

I'm expecting to be able to omit any redundant x, y and not double book seats in the cinema.

Comment: By ‘duplicate entries’, do you mean two equal entries in the first list, or two equal entries in the second list? Or two equal entries from either list? Or two equal entries, one from each list, at the same index? (I'm guessing the latter, from your mention of `zip()`, but it's not clear.) And what do you want to do if you find duplicate entries — stop with an error message? Or filter them out and continue processing (possibly returning a list of error messages as well)? And what do you mean by ‘in the other function’? Can you explain the relevant aspects of the ‘Cinema Manager’ project?

Comment: It would really help if you could post the code you have so far — or, better, a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) — to show exactly what you mean.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I apologize for not being more clear. I have two lists that I have paired with zip into x, y coordinates on a grid.

selectedRowList.zip(selectedSeatsList).forEach { pair-> cinema[pair.first][pair.second] = "B" }
B = booked seat that is in the grid. I have two functions that kind of divide the displayed grid. One takes the booked seat and one displays the booked and available seats.  I need to return a response when a seat is already booked and not double book a seat. I hope that adds some clarity. Thanks again for responding so quickly.

Comment: Thanks, that makes your question much clearer. This isn't a proper answer, but in my experience code that uses parallel arrays/lists like this often works better with a list of objects instead. (That avoids the risk of the two lists getting different sizes, and the need to zip them together.) You could have a list of `Pair<Int, Int>`s, though you might find some benefit in writing your own e.g. `data class Coord` instead. (Kotlin makes it very easy to write simple classes like that.) Then it's easier to read, and you can use tools like `distinct()`, `groupBy()`, etc. to manage duplicates.

Comment: Yes, the typical way to do this would be with a single list of some data class to represent your coordinates. Having separate lists of all the pieces of something that go together is convoluted. If things go together, they should be combined in a class.